# How can I, in Microsoft Lync automatically accept a desktop sharing request from WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, lync

How can I, in Microsoft Lync client automatically accept a desktop sharing request **programmatically** in WPF, and also How can I put it in **fullscreen** mode?

Comment: @TomTom, you should have put that as an answer, as it's basically the right response :)

Answer (score 2):

Not at all? Sorry. You know, there are serious security implications allowing this.

Comment: @RamiSakr accepting a request for a desktop-share automatically has no security implication?  How did you figure this out?